# winapi - AppendMenu - text layout

Tags: winapi

I use the following code to append an item to the context menu:

```
contextMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
AppendMenu(contextMenu, MF_STRING, 0, L"PASTE");
```

Is it possible to set a text layout and margins around the text? By default a context menu looks [this](https://ibb.co/dmgDy1w) way. It looks like there is no left or center alignment. Margins are quite big.

Comment: The margin is there for a reason: Towards the left, there's room for icons, whereas the space towards the right is reserved to display keyboard shortcuts. I'm not sure you can change that. You might want to try using [owner-drawn menu items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-menus#creating-owner-drawn-menu-items).

Comment: This seems to be by design, as the comments say, which leaves room for the front and back. Workaround is to use spaces to make it appear centered.

Comment: But this is not reliable when the menu added later increases the size of the menu bar.